# Sql Server 2005 Memory Management - Server Properties (Memory Page)

Tags: sql-server-2005

Which are the recommended values for the Memory settings:

- A)Use AWE to allocate memory ?
- B)Maximum server memory (in MB) ?
- C)Maximum server memory (in MB) ?

My production scenario is that we are using the same machine that hosts SQL Server to do run other applications.

The machine has:
 1. A) 3.21GB or RAM
 2. B) Runs Microsoft Office
 3. C) Is an Intel duo core 2.59Hz

Answer (score 0):

It depends... You should specify (at least):

1. How much RAM installed in your server
2. SQL Server / Windows server edition
3. How many 'other applications' runs on that server and how much RAM it need to use